# Inconsistent rounding between Crystal Reports (preview) and Crystal Reports Viewer (export)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer

I have a report that displays different rates for different items. One of these items is "mileage" and has a rate that has fractional cents (`0.565`).

We want to display the full `0.565` for these rates, and show all other rates with two decimal places.

To facilitate this, I used a formula in `Format Field > Number > Customize` for both `Decimals` and `Rounding` that looks basically like this:

`if({RATE_TYPE}='MILEAGE')then 3 else 2`

This appears to be working correctly in Crystal Reports. For mileage, 3 decimal places are shown, and it is rounding to 3 decimal places.

In Crystal Reports Viewer (and subsequent exports), it is showing 3 decimal places *but* it is rounding to 2 decimal places.

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 (12.3.0.601), and Crystal Reports Viewer:

```
<system.web>
  <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
    <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
      <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
  ...
  <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#">
    <assemblies>
      ...
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      ...
    </assemblies>
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".rpt" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.Compilation.RptBuildProvider, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
  ...
  <httpHandlers>
    ...
    <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    ...
  </httpHandlers>
  ...
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <handlers>
    ...
    <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    ...
  </handlers>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

(sorry about the wall of code)

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a known fix?

Comment: What is your default value for the decimal places?

Comment: The values in the drop-downs are `1.00` and `0.01`, I'll change those both to three-digit values and see what happens.

Comment: You will have to in order for it to work

Comment: That doesn't explain why it is working correctly in the report previewer inside of the Crystal Reports editor.

Comment: I can't answer why it works in Designer but not in the Viewer, I just know that you have to set the defaults to the maximum you want to achieve and then use a formula to change it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set your default values for decimals and rounding to the maximum amount you are trying to achieve. So in your case it would be 3.

Comment: This appears to have done the trick. Could you explain why this is necessary, and why it shows up correctly in the report preview inside of Crystal Reports but Crystal Reports viewer does not show up correctly?

Comment: Think of it like an array. You will need to set the maximum size possible first so it can hold all the values, then dynamically make it smaller. Make sense? As to why it works in Designer and not in the Viewer, I really don't know.